# Drush cannot connect to the database when updating

Tags: database, drush, updating, composer

I am trying to update Drupal from version 8.7.5 to 8.7.7.  I installed Drupal using composer and had a really old version of Drush that I had installed from apt-get.  I uninstalled the old version and installed an up to date version.  However, I still cannot update the database, I think because it doesn't connect.  Drupal itself can connect to the database (obviously because the site has been up and running for months and I have not changed anything other than to try to update things) but for some reason Drush cannot.  Weirdly, when I do `drush status`, it shows a Drupal version of 8.7.3, which is not correct.  I have tried doing `drush cache:clear` it clears everything but does not change any of the issues.  When I do `drush rebuild` I get ' SQLSTATE[HY000] [1044] Access denied for user 'user'@'%' to database 'database'`.
Any help in getting drush to connect to the database would be much appreciated.  Thanks.

**drush status**

```
 Drupal version : 8.7.3                                             
 Site URI       : http://default                                    
 DB driver      : mysql                                             
 DB hostname    : localhost                                         
 DB port        : 3306                                              
 DB username    : joomla                                            
 DB name        : otherrealmdrupal                                  
 PHP binary     : /usr/bin/php7.3                                   
 PHP config     : /etc/php/7.3/cli/php.ini                          
 PHP OS         : Linux                                             
 Drush script   : /usr/bin/drush                                    
 Drush version  : 9.7.1                                             
 Drush temp     : /tmp                                              
 Drush configs  : /root/.drush/drush.yml                            
                  /var/www/html/drupal/vendor/drush/drush/drush.yml 
 Drupal root    : /var/www/html/drupal                              
 Site path      : sites/default
```

**drush updatedb**

```
Drush Launcher Version: 0.6.0
ROOT: /var/www/html/drupal
DRUSH VERSION: 9
DRUPAL ROOT: /var/www/html/drupal
COMPOSER ROOT: /var/www/html/drupal
VENDOR ROOT: /var/www/html/drupal/vendor
 [preflight] Config paths: /root/.drush/drush.yml,/var/www/html/drupal/vendor/drush/drush/drush.yml
 [preflight] Alias paths: /root/.drush/sites,/etc/drush/sites,/var/www/html/drupal/drush/sites,/var/www/html/drush/sites
 [preflight] Commandfile search paths: /var/www/html/drupal/vendor/drush/drush/src
 [bootstrap] Starting bootstrap to full [0.22 sec, 8.49 MB]
 [bootstrap] Drush bootstrap phase 5 [0.22 sec, 8.49 MB]
 [bootstrap] Try to validate bootstrap phase 5 [0.22 sec, 8.49 MB]
 [bootstrap] Try to validate bootstrap phase 5 [0.22 sec, 8.49 MB]
 [bootstrap] Try to bootstrap at phase 5 [0.22 sec, 8.49 MB]
 [bootstrap] Drush bootstrap phase: bootstrapDrupalRoot() [0.22 sec, 8.49 MB]
 [bootstrap] Change working directory to /var/www/html/drupal [0.22 sec, 8.49 MB]
 [bootstrap] Initialized Drupal 8.7.3 root directory at /var/www/html/drupal [0.23 sec, 8.62 MB]
 [bootstrap] Try to validate bootstrap phase 5 [0.23 sec, 8.62 MB]
 [bootstrap] Try to bootstrap at phase 5 [0.24 sec, 8.92 MB]
 [bootstrap] Drush bootstrap phase: bootstrapDrupalSite() [0.24 sec, 8.92 MB]
 [bootstrap] Initialized Drupal site default at sites/default [0.24 sec, 9.15 MB]
 [bootstrap] Try to validate bootstrap phase 5 [0.24 sec, 9.15 MB]
 [bootstrap] Try to bootstrap at phase 5 [0.24 sec, 9.15 MB]
 [bootstrap] Drush bootstrap phase: bootstrapDrupalConfiguration() [0.24 sec, 9.15 MB]
 [debug] Add service modifier [0.25 sec, 9.38 MB]
 [bootstrap] Try to validate bootstrap phase 5 [0.25 sec, 9.38 MB]
 [bootstrap] Unable to connect to database. More information may be available by running `drush status`. This may occur when Drush is trying to bootstrap a site that has not been installed or does not have a configured database. In this case you can select another site with a working database setup by specifying the URI to use with the --uri parameter on the command line. See `drush topic docs-aliases` for details. [0.26 sec, 9.63 MB]
 [bootstrap] Could not bootstrap at phase 5 [0.26 sec, 9.62 MB]

In BootstrapHook.php line 32:

  [Exception]                                                         
  Bootstrap failed. Run your command with -vvv for more information.  


Exception trace:
  at /var/www/html/drupal/vendor/drush/drush/src/Boot/BootstrapHook.php:32
 Drush\Boot\BootstrapHook->initialize() at /var/www/html/drupal/vendor/consolidation/annotated-command/src/Hooks/Dispatchers/InitializeHookDispatcher.php:34
 Consolidation\AnnotatedCommand\Hooks\Dispatchers\InitializeHookDispatcher->callInitializeHook() at /var/www/html/drupal/vendor/consolidation/annotated-command/src/Hooks/Dispatchers/InitializeHookDispatcher.php:27
 Consolidation\AnnotatedCommand\Hooks\Dispatchers\InitializeHookDispatcher->initialize() at /var/www/html/drupal/vendor/consolidation/annotated-command/src/CommandProcessor.php:145
 Consolidation\AnnotatedCommand\CommandProcessor->initializeHook() at /var/www/html/drupal/vendor/consolidation/annotated-command/src/AnnotatedCommand.php:289
 Consolidation\AnnotatedCommand\AnnotatedCommand->initialize() at /var/www/html/drupal/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:221
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at /var/www/html/drupal/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:981
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at /var/www/html/drupal/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:254
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at /var/www/html/drupal/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:147
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at /var/www/html/drupal/vendor/drush/drush/src/Runtime/Runtime.php:118
 Drush\Runtime\Runtime->doRun() at /var/www/html/drupal/vendor/drush/drush/src/Runtime/Runtime.php:49
 Drush\Runtime\Runtime->run() at /var/www/html/drupal/vendor/drush/drush/drush.php:72
 require() at /var/www/html/drupal/vendor/drush/drush/includes/preflight.inc:18
 drush_main() at phar:///usr/bin/drush/bin/drush.php:141
 require() at /usr/bin/drush:10

updatedb [--cache-clear [CACHE-CLEAR]] [--entity-updates] [--post-updates [POST-UPDATES]] [--no-cache-clear] [--no-post-updates] [-h|--help] [-q|--quiet] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-V|--version] [--ansi] [--no-ansi] [-n|--no-interaction] [-d|--debug] [-y|--yes] [--no] [--remote-host REMOTE-HOST] [--remote-user REMOTE-USER] [-r|--root ROOT] [-l|--uri URI] [--simulate] [--pipe] [-D|--define DEFINE] [--notify [NOTIFY]] [--druplicon] [--xh-link XH-LINK] [--] <command>
```

Comment: Drush is supposed to be installed as local dependency, not globally anymore. See https://docs.drush.org/en/master/install/ on the very top. Then it's `cd web && ../vendor/drush/drush/drush status` or you install [Drush Launcher](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush-launcher) on your server then it's just `cd web && drush status` as usual. Please see if having a local Drush and calling it from the correct directory fixes your problem. Many thanks

Comment: Hey, did you find out the problem with this? I'm facing exactly the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

Finally figured out the problem.

Just change the host line in your settings.local.php:

```
'host' => '127.0.0.1',
```